# How to leave puppeteer scraping 24/7 and checking if element disappears in real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

so I eventually want to have this running on a cloud platform like digital ocean running 24/7. The purpose of it is to see if items on amazon go in or out of stock. Currently, my code does not do what I want because it only loads the page once and only proceeds if the button exists. How can I get it to log if the button does not exist on the page and continually load to get real-time results?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;





async function monitor() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36');
        page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
        await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/PULSE-3D-Wireless-Headset-PlayStation-5/dp/B08FC6QLKN/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=ps5&qid=1622262855&sr=8-1//');       

        await page.waitForSelector('#add-to-cart-button'); 
        await page.reload(load)
        console.log("In Stock")

} catch (e) {
    console.log('our error', e);
}
    };



monitor()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a while loop

```
while(true){
  try {
    await page.waitForSelector('#add-to-cart-button')
    break        
  } catch(e) {
    await page.reload()
  }
}
```